# QDialog window modality

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, dialog, modal-dialog

Is there a way of opening a QDialog window-modal with exec()?
open() returns immediately, and exec() shows the dialog application-modal instead of window-modal.
How to take the best of both methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Qt there exist [window-modality](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowModality-enum).

For example, showing a dialog this way, from inside a QWidget-derived class, will make the dialog window-modal to its parent:

```
  QDialog d(this);
  //...
  d.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
  d.exec();
```

being `this` a `QWidget`, set as the `QDialog` parent.

Comment: I have tried this, but my child dialog had been refusing to show unless I provided NULL as its parent. I fixed it with removing setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint) from the dialog's constructor.